# How to prevent Biome from linting a build directory inside a Monorepo?

Tags: javascript, biomejs

Given a Monorepo based on Turborepo I want to use Biome for linting and formatting. Based on [the docs](https://biomejs.dev/reference/configuration/#extends) I created a package at `./biome-configuration` with a base.json

```
{
    "files": {
        "ignore": ["dist", "./dist", "./dist/**", "./dist/**/*"]
    }
}
```

and a vite-library.json

```
{
    "extends": ["./base.json"]
}
```

My library at `./packages/my-library` needs its own configuration file but only extends the basic one

```
{
    "extends": ["../../biome-configuration/vite-library.json"]
}
```

Unfortunately my library still tries to lint its own `dist` directory. As you see in the [`ignore`](https://biomejs.dev/reference/configuration/#filesinclude) section I tried multiple Unix patterns but that doesn't seem to work.

It seems I must add this to the configuration file inside my library project.

Is there a fix for my pattern? I know that every project needs to ignore the `dist` directory.